# changing a js file location only when the source-code is showed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i'm trying to change a js file location when a visitor shows the source-code
 , depending on that :

> javascript functions don't work when the visitor shows the source-code
>   .

my idea is creating a file , put a javascript code to delete the file , in this situation the file won't be deleted if someone showed the source-code :

```
$check="$ip-$views-$id";
fopen("$check.txt","w");  //CREATING A FILE
// DELETING THE FILE ABOVE BY JAVASCRIPT , IT WON'T BE DELETED IF SOMEONE ENTERED VIA THE SOURCE-CODE MODE
?>
<div id="countno"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#countno').load('del.php?name=<?echo $check;?>&location=' + ' #countno');
</script>
<?

if (file_exists("$check.txt")) { //IF SOMEONE SHOWED THE SOURCE CODE
$new_location="fake_location.js";
}
else{
$new_location=$old_location;
}
?>
<script src="<?echo $new_location;?>"></script>
```

the problem now , is that the file_exists php function shows that the file still exists even though it was already deleted by the javascript code .

> the file_exists function was executed before the javascript code !

any help / solution to make that php function check the file after that javascript code ? i know it's kinda impossible but it worth it !

Comment: Are you talking about when someone views the source code from the browser? You want to have it delete the js file so they can't view your code?

Comment: Yes when someone views the source code ! but not like that .. when someone shows the source code , the file i created [ check the code ] won't be deleted [ javascript deleting code dosen't work on the source code ] then , my idea was checking if that file still exists , if it does ! then i'll change the location.js to a fake_location.js that will be shown in the source-code .

Comment: I am still not sure i get what you are saying but if you are talking about trying to keep your JavaScript safe from people copying it, then you would need to encrypt it with something because it loads to the browser so it's not like you can do anything about it at that point after the page loads. Even if you could get the file to delete  on viewing source, then the page wouldn't work because it needs the JavaScript.

Comment: Also if someone disables their JavaScript then that circumvents your method.

Comment: Well they can still see the js code, the JavaScript just doesn't work on the page is all.

Comment: if someone disabled their javascript then , the file that was created by php won't be deleted too ! and the method still works , the fake_location will be shown .. i think you didn't get what i'm trying to do but i'm really thankful for your help in this :)
the whole code above is a correct way to detected if a visitor is in the "view-source" mode or not .
if it is "show fake_location" , if not "works normally" .
the only problem i'm having is that the "file_exists" works before the javascript code , so it shows that the file is there even when it's deleted by that javascript code .

Comment: dude it dosen't matter if the js code was shown in the source , it won't work and the deleting won't work if you were showing source and from that i'll get that this visitor is using the show-source mode .

Comment: PHP runs before javascript, php is server-executed, javascript is client (browser) executed. There is no reversing the order of that. Secondly, if someone views source, it's to "borrow" your code so it doesn't matter if it doesn't work in your site (when they disable javascript to disable your view source trigger), they will have it and implement it in their site...

Comment: yeah i totally get the first thing , But secondly , i don't care if they got it or if they wanted to borrow it , my goal isn't hiding the source , what i'm trying to say if that "deleting code" didn't work ! it means the file won't be deleted and by that i'll know that this user is showing the source !

Comment: my code says : each visitor creates a unique file ! and each visitor should delete that file by javascript , so if a visitor didn't delete the file he created , then he is viewing the site from the source [ if you showed the source you'll only see that javascript code but it won't works ] .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is not possible. [php](/questions/tagged/php) is a server side language while [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) is a client side language. Thus, the PHP on your page will always execute before the Javascript on your page executes. There is no way to make your Javascript execute first when you have it this way.

Instead, what you could do is to separate the PHP and Javascript. Have your `file_exists` check in another page. e.g. `check.php`.

```
if (file_exists("$check.txt")) {
    echo "fake_location.js";
} else {
    echo $old_location;
}
```

Then use an ajax call to make a request to `check.php`, and load your other script depending on what `check.php` outputs.

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "check.php"
})
.done(function(script) {
    $("#check").attr("src", script);
});
</script>

<script id="check"></script>
```

However, if your goal is to prevent people from figuring out where your javascript is located, it is not possible. Most browsers nowadays can inspect the HTML as it changes. They can see the loaded script without having to load the source separately.